# In Grails using DataSourse I am trying to insert data but only id field is get save another field are save

Tags: grails

I am trying to insert data to Oracle db and only id filed got inserted rest of the filed had null value.

Customer domain class:

```
package com.app

class Customer {

   def customerId

   def customerName

   def userName

   def password

   def email

   def contactNum;

   //def Address address;

   static mapping = {
      table name:"AACUSTOMER"
      version false
      customerId column:'ID', generator: 'sequence', params:[sequence:'AACUSTOMER_ID_SEQ']
      customerName column:'CUSTOMER_NAME'
      userName column:'USERNAME'
      password column:'PASSWORD'
      email column:'EMAIL'
      contactNum column:'CONTACT_NUM'
   }
}
```

customerController:

```
package com.app

class CustomerController {

   def index() { 
      render(view:"addCustomer")
   }

   def addCustomer() {

      def name = params.name
      def username = params.username
      def password = params.pwd
      def repassword = params.rpwd
      def email = params.email
      def contactNum = params.contactnum
      if(password==repassword) {
         Customer customer = new Customer();
         customer.setCustomerName(name)
         customer.setUserName(username)
         customer.setPassword(password)
         customer.setEmail(email)
         customer.setContactNum(contactNum)
         println "${customer.getCustomerName()}"
         customer.save(flush: true);
      }
      else {
         render(message:"password should match")
      }
   }
}
```

Datasource.groovy:

```
dataSource {
   pooled = true
   driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
   username = "wmdev"
   password = "wmdev"
   url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.20.1.196:1521/LCLWMSDEV01"
}

hibernate {
   cache.use_second_level_cache = true
   cache.use_query_cache = false
   cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
//    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegiossnFactory' // Hibernate 
}

// environment specific settings

environments {
   development {
      dataSource {
         dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
         url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.20.1.196:1521/LCLWMSDEV01"
      }
   }

   test {
      dataSource {
         dbCreate = "create-drop"
         url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.20.1.196:1521/LCLWMSDEV01"
      }
   }

   production {
      dataSource {
         dbCreate = "update"
         url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.20.1.196:1521/LCLWMSDEV01"
         properties {
            maxActive = -1
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
            numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
            testOnBorrow=true
            testWhileIdle=true
            testOnReturn=false
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            jdbcInterceptors="ConnectionState"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're being way too "groovy". GORM domain class properties must be typed, and have a standard type that GORM ad Hibernate know how to persist, or you need to provide a `CustomType` implementation to do the persistence work for it. If you don't type a class property it's ignored because there's no way to know that `userName` is probably a String (but it could also be the primary key, and need to be treated differently from the other properties, or that customerId might be a Long and a foreign key into the Customer domain class and customer table, or a String (and still possibly a PK/FK). You need to provide some information to get things started.

Comment: Excellent - progress is good :)  Use the http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration plugin (or another plugin or library if you prefer) to create changelogs and you'll always be able to keep your code and database in sync.

Comment: insert into AAEMPLOYEE (id, CONTACTNUM, EMAIL, ID, EMP_NAME, PASSWORD, USERNAME) values (hibernate_sequence.nextval, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: In this query my grail-app is taking id in two time and throwing exception ORA-00957: duplicate column name

Comment: That must be because you're using uppercase override names. But there's no need for that here - every override you specified is exactly the name that would have been used without the those settings, except for `userName`, which would have been `user_name`, and also that HIBERNATE DOESN'T YELL ALL OF ITS TABLE AND COLUMN NAMES. Either drop one of the columns, or drop the table and let Hibernate build it again. Avoid `dbCreate='update'` because it does strange things like this. Use `create-drop` until things stabilize and then use migrations.

Comment: Ya its taking id filed two time now my data got inserted Thanks lot